# Have a Object key value equal the value of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So what I the basics is that I am trying to put in mutiple values into a for loop .

I can do one at a time but I am trying to do multiple  values.
my html

```
    <form  class="form1 "action="">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="v" >
        
    </form>
```

my javascript

```
let answers2 = document.getElementById('fname').value;
console.log(answers2.split(''));
let answersString = answers2.split('');
console.log(typeof answersString);
var answersObject = _.invert(answersString);

for (let i = 0; i < answers5.length; i++) {
  if (M2060[answersObject]) {
    let soultion1 = "M" + ((20 + 20).toString() + "," + (60 + 00).toString() + " " + M2060[answers2]);
```

for example here is the object of M2060

```
var M2060 = {
  "B" : [
    " v-40  a20,10 0 0 1 0,20   a20,10 0 0 1 0,20 ",
   ],
   "H" : [
    " v-40 v20 h20 v20 v-40 ",
    // need to move down
   ],
   "I" : [
    " h20 h-10 v-40 h10 h-20 ",
    // need to move down
   ],
   "N" : [
    " v-36  l20,40  v-40  ",
  ],
  
}
```

and M3060

```
 var M3060 = {
  "T" : [
    " v-40 h10 h-20 ",
  ],
  "t" : [
    " v-20 v10 h10 h-20 "
   ],
 }
```

So lets say I put in Bt in my html which are in two differnt objects

answers2 collects the value you put in the html

answersString changes it into an object array
where it would be

```
0: "B"
1: "t"
```

but answersObject changes it to

```
"B": 0 
"t": 1
```

how can I have them both go into my if statement and collect the value connected  to the key that they are both assigned to in a different object ?

tldr : how can I have MUTIPLE values detect that their values are the same as the key of another object and changes the key to the key of the object .
That the original key = the value.

EDIT:
So I guess the simplest way I can say this is lets

Say in a object 0: ["g"] and 1 :["H"]

and in another object g: "wow" and "H" :[Help]

how can I get "g" from 0 to change to "wow" which in a different object
so  0 would = 0: ["wow"]
but at the same time 1 would change to 1: ["Help"].

Comment: May I ask you to rephrase your question, please? I am having some difficulties understanding what you want to do and the code you wrote (for example, why are `M2060.B` and `M2060.H` arrays? Can they contain more than a single string?) It might also be useful to use more meaningful / self-explanatory names in your code.

Comment: Sure the reason why M2060 and M3060 are written that way is because those are the starting move to paths for each key .
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp

The array part I am trying to do it that way since I want each letter/number separate .